# Increment counter by pressing a button with output to leds

Tags: vhdl

I have this simple code which doesn't behave as it should and can't figure out why.

```
entity test is
port (D0        : in  std_logic;
        output      : out unsigned(6 downto 0));
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is
    signal clk_Cent_i : unsigned(6 downto 0);
begin

    gen_clk : process (D0)
    begin
    if  D0 = '1' then
    clk_Cent_i<=clk_Cent_i + "1";
    end if;
    end process gen_clk;
output<= clk_Cent_i; 
end Behavioral;
```

I want by pressing a button to increment a counter and show the counters' number to 7 leds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count individual presses, you need to react on signal edges. So, instead of

```
if  D0 = '1' then
```

you need to write

```
if(rising_edge(D0)) then
```

Warning: this will only work if `D0` is correctly [debounced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce), i.e. a single rising edge is produced on each press.

Comment: This will make D0 a clock signal. The switch will likely fail the timings. Better to set up an FSM to monitor the state of the switch on each clock edge.